# Is there any way to set maximum length constraint on each row of a textarea field?

Tags: html, textarea

I need to fulfill a unique requirement from my client.
Attached here is the image,[image]

I need to force the user not to enter more than 15 digits per row of a `<textarea>` field without any spaces. Is this possible with HTML?

I thought of using `cols` attribute but then it collapses like as shown below, without any empty spaces desired as such in the first image.

[image]

Comment: @BalusC: I have a constraint to do this with a JSF tag only.

Comment: This is a HTML problem. JSF is just a HTML code generator. You'd have had exactly the same problem when having just a `.html` file. Once you get the answer, just alter JSF in such way that it generates exactly the desired HTML (and JS) output as indicated by the answer or duplicate.

Comment: "*Is this possible with HTML?*" - no; this would require JavaScript.

Comment: @David Thomas: Please suggest then.

Comment: This would be difficult to implement, can you use a single textbox and add the entries into a div/ul?

Comment: David Nguyen: Didn't get you. I need to add those entries in a text area box only.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that JavaScript is a possibility, since this seems to be impossible with HTML, I'd suggest:

```
function check() {
    // the trimmed current-value of the <select>
    // 'this' is passed automagically from the
    // addEventListener() method;
    // String.prototype.trim() removes leading and
    // trailing white-space from the value:
    var content = this.value.trim(),

        // splitting that value string into an array
        // using String.prototype.split(); breaking it
        // apart on new-line characters:
        lines = content.split(/\n/),

        // creating a regular expression object to
        // match a simple pattern of any-character
        // except the new-line occurring a minimum
        // of zero, and a maximum of two, times (.{0,2})
        // that is surrounded by the beginning (^) and
        // the end ($) of the string:
        reg = /^.{0,2}$/,

        // using Array.prototype.every() to check
        // that every line in the array matches
        // the regular expression, tested using
        // RegExp.prototype.test(). This method
        // returns a Boolean true (every line 
        // matches the assessment) or false
        // (at least one line does not match):
        test = lines.every(function (line) {
            // the first argument (here: 'line')
            // of the anonymous function is the 
            // current array-element of the array
            // over which we're iterating:
            return reg.test(line);
        });

    // if the string (with leading/trailing white-space
    // removed) has a length (is not zero):
    if (content.length) {

        // ...and test is true:
        if (test) {
            // we use the HTMLElement.classList API
            // to add the 'valid' class-name:
            this.classList.add('valid');

             // and remove the 'invalid' class-name:
            this.classList.remove('invalid');

        // otherwise:
        } else {
            // we do the reverse:
            this.classList.add('invalid');
            this.classList.remove('valid');
        }
    // if the trimmed content has a length of zero:
    } else {
        // we remove both 'invalid' and 'valid' class-names:
        this.classList.remove('invalid','valid');
    }
}

// retrieving the first element of the document
// that matches the supplied CSS selector:
var textarea = document.querySelector('textarea');

// binding the check() function as the 'keyup'
// event-handler:
textarea.addEventListener('keyup', check);
```

```js
function check() {
  var content = this.value.trim(),
    lines = content.split(/\n/),
    reg = /^.{0,2}$/,
    test = lines.every(function(line) {
      return reg.test(line);
    });
  if (content.length) {
    if (test) {
      this.classList.add('valid');
      this.classList.remove('invalid');
    } else {
      this.classList.add('invalid');
      this.classList.remove('valid');
    }
  } else {
    this.classList.remove('invalid', 'valid');
  }
}

var textarea = document.querySelector('textarea');

textarea.addEventListener('keyup', check);
```

```css
textarea,
.validity {
  width: 40%;
  margin: 0 0 0.5em 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  transition: all 0.5s linear;
}
textarea {
  border: 2px solid #000;
}
textarea.valid {
  border-color: #0f0;
}
textarea.invalid {
  border-color: #f00;
}
span.validity {
  color: #999;
  display: block;
  border-bottom: 2px solid transparent;
}
textarea.invalid + span.validity {
  color: #000;
  border-bottom-color: #f90;
}
```

```html
<form action="#" method="post">
  <fieldset>
    <textarea title="Each line must have less than three characters."></textarea>
    <span class="validity">Each line must have less than three characters.</span>
  </fieldset>
</form>
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/w5hwrkft/), for easier experimentation/development.

I realise that this isn't quite what you wanted, but while HTML does allow for the `pattern` attribute to specify a regular expression that the user-entered value should match (for the element to be considered valid) it doesn't seem to support the use of flags (which in JavaScript regular expressions would be `m`, to allow the `^` and `$` characters to represent the beginning and end, respectively, for each line).

A simple demonstration of `pattern`, specifying that a text `<input />` element should have at most five characters in the range of a-z (lower-case), using the `:invalid` selector to visually indicate the invalid-entry:

```css
input {
  border-width: 5px;
}
input:valid {
  border-color: #0f0;
}
input:invalid {
  border-color: #f00;
}
input + span::before {
  content: 'in';
  transition: color 0.6s linear;
}
input:valid + span::before {
  color: transparent;
}
input:invalid + span::before {
  color: #000;
}
input + span::after {
  content: 'valid';
}
```

```html
<input type="text" pattern="[a-z]{0,5}" title="Any five lower-case characters from 'a' to 'z' only." />
<span></span>
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/w5hwrkft/1).

References:

- CSS:

  - [CSS Adjacent-sibling (`+`) combinator](http://www.w3.org/TR/selectors/#adjacent-sibling-combinators).
  - [CSS Transitions](http://dev.w3.org/csswg/css-transitions/).
  - [CSS validity selectors, `:invalid` and `:valid`](http://www.w3.org/TR/selectors4/#validity-pseudos).
- HTML:

  - [`pattern` attribute](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/forms.html#the-pattern-attribute).
- JavaScript:

  - [`Array.prototype.every()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/every).
  - [`document.querySelector()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelector).
  - [`Element.classList` API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/classList).
  - [Guide to JavaScript Regular Expressions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions).
  - [`String.prototype.split()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split).
  - [`String.prototype.trim()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/trim).

Comment: I am fascinated by your fascination for making information work. You deserve not just highly reputation from my side but were I living close to you, I have would dropped by your location in person to thank you for your help/support.  May that happen someday. Thank you once again.

Comment: You're very welcome indeed; I'm glad to have helped! Even though I know it's not quite what you would have preferred.